# Change in IsPostBack behavior between IIS 7.5 and IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, iis-8.5

I'm helping someone move an IIS 7.5 ASP .net 3.5 WebFroms application to IIS 8.5 server. but we have run into an issue and can't figure out why. We think it might be just different behavior betweens IIS versions. If it is, is there a way to go back? 
The web applications contains a page where the form does a post to a different webpage and passes some info in the form body. On IIS 7.5 when a check for IsPostBack is done in the code the value returned is false, however now that it has been moved to IIS 8.5 the same check is returned true. I haven't been able to find anything about this using google.

Comment: IIS version shouldn't make a difference in behavior.

Comment: That is what I would have though but the code hasn't changed and IIS 7.5 deployment says IsPostBack == false IIS 8.5 deployment IsPostBack == true

Comment: and is should not be a PostBack the page is being loaded for the first time. Using the Post Method. The Post was done from a different web page so it it not posting to itself.

Comment: Is the target page an extensionless URL (e.g. a default page)?